# PyQt5 List Widget Programmatically select all items

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I add multiple items to a list widget, then it sets the last item to the selected item. I would like add multiple items and have them all selected. How do I do this?

Comment: All the items or just the ones added?

Comment: Would [getting the list item](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#item) and then [making it selected](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#setSelected) work (and doing that for each item you want to have selected)?

Comment: I need all items selected. That doesn't work because each item that gets selected causes previous item to be deselected.

Comment: So, do you have a QListWidget and want to add many QListWidgetItem that get selected after adding them? Is that what you want?

Comment: @JosuéCortina Yes, so the end result is that all items added are selected. And when I call selectedItems(), I get back a list of all items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the selectionMode to `QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.listwidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listwidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.listwidget)
        # add some items
        for i in range(5):
            self.listwidget.addItem(str(i))

        # add items with selection
        for i in range(5):
            it = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(str(i))
            self.listwidget.addItem(it)
            it.setSelected(True)

        # selected items
        for item in self.listwidget.selectedItems():
            print(item.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This worked, but I think it has more to do with "it.setSelected(True)" than it does with MultiSelection. It just cant be SingleSelection or NoSelection.